# Entity Framework - Naming a "autogenerated" table on InverseProperty

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

I did a bit of searching but can't find a same problem / question.
I have a question regarding the table naming (in the database) when EF creates a table encountering InverseProperty DataAnnotation

"Dummy/Demo code" :

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Event> InvitedEvents { get; set;}
    public virtual List<Event> AcceptedEvents { get; set;}
    public virtual List<Event> DeclinedEvents { get; set;}
}

public class Event
{
    public String Name { get; set;}

   [InverseProperty("InvitedEvents")]
   public virtual List<User> InvitedUsers { get; set; }
   [InverseProperty("AcceptedEvents")]
   public virtual List<User> AcceptedUsers { get; set; }
   [InverseProperty("DeclinedEvents")]
   public virtual List<User> DeclinedUsers { get; set; }

}
```

This all works and the lookup tables is created, but my question is
***How can i give that table a name ?***

They are now named (something like)
 - EventUser
 - EventUser_1
 - EventUser_2

I want to give some more "readable" names to it.

Hope it's clear.

**UPDATE!**

As answered by [Ladislav Mrnka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413501/ladislav-mrnka), fluent API was the solution. I removed the [InverseProperty] properties and added the creation of relations to the DataContext class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
        .HasMany(e => e.InvitedEvents )
        .WithMany(u => u.InvitedUsers )
        .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.ToTable("%TABLENAME%");
                mc.MapLeftKey("UniqueId");
                mc.MapRightKey("UniqueId");
             });
}
```

You need to make sure that each class contains a UniqueId column (in my demo example EventId, UserId)

Comment: You can only do that with fluent API.

Comment: Thanks that indeed was the answer, to bad i didn't found it myself. I removed the DataAnnotation properties and added Fluent API in the DataContext and work likes a charm, thanks again

Comment: Too sad it isn't possible with DataAnnotations !

Comment: Hi, would you mind to move your **UPDATE** to an answer and mark it as accepted? I wanted to mark _another_ question as a duplicate of this one, but only questions with accepted answers are eligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer also updated in answer

As answered by Ladislav Mrnka, fluent API was the solution. I removed the [InverseProperty] properties and added the creation of relations to the DataContext class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
        .HasMany(e => e.InvitedEvents )
        .WithMany(u => u.InvitedUsers )
        .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.ToTable("%TABLENAME%");
                mc.MapLeftKey("UniqueId");
                mc.MapRightKey("UniqueId");
             });
}
```